# What do you say when you feel bad for someone? Like "Poor Alice."

Tags: grammar, translation, nouns, na-adjectives

When you feel bad for someone or feel sympathy for them? For example, if you want to say, "Poor Alice," would it be, 可哀想アリス？or do I have to add the な after 可哀想 since it's a na-adjective?

Answer (score 2):

It would be 可哀想なアリス for poor Alice. But don't say that to her face, this is used when talking to another person about Alice.

Comment: Ah okay, thank you for answering!